# Issue with deployment of sails.js app on Heroku - npm error - package: sailshq/body-parser

Tags: heroku, deployment, npm, sails.js, body-parser

To start, current configuration - Development machine:

- Node version: 8.4.0
- Npm: 5.3.0 (comes with 8.4)
- Sails: ~0.12.13
- Source control system: Github
- Deployment host: Heroku

I followed following guide: https://vort3x.me/sailsjs-heroku/ (except the heroku git part, working with github)

But I am rather stuck when I press deploy in Heroku, the following happens:

```
-----> Creating runtime environment        

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true

       NODE_VERBOSE=false

       NODE_ENV=production

       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false

-----> Installing binaries

       engines.node (package.json):  8.4.0

       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)



       Resolving node version 8.4.0...

       Downloading and installing node 8.4.0...

       Detected package-lock.json: defaulting npm to version 5.x.x

       Bootstrapping npm 5.x.x (replacing 5.3.0)...

       npm 5.3.0 installed

-----> Restoring cache

       Skipping cache restore (disabled)

-----> Building dependencies

       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_7f8d8515578971e692c2e6a35e1006d2/bdemolder-boardgamenights-f5eda42/node_modules/.staging/sails-fec6f6e5/node_modules/@sailshq/body-parser

       npm ERR! code ENOENT

       npm ERR! errno -2

       npm ERR! syscall rename

       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/tmp/build_7f8d8515578971e692c2e6a35e1006d2/bdemolder-boardgamenights-f5eda42/node_modules/.staging/sails-fec6f6e5/node_modules/@sailshq/body-parser' -> '/tmp/build_7f8d8515578971e692c2e6a35e1006d2/bdemolder-boardgamenights-f5eda42/node_modules/.staging/@sailshq/body-parser-9ed21a9f'

       npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

       npm ERR! enoent



       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

       npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-08-22T20_43_13_796Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed
```

And frankly I have no idea what to do about this, I thought first it was because I forgot to say engine 'node: 8.4.0' and that my cache was corrupted, so I tried disabling cache, but nothing so far.

It says to rename, but I have no control over dependencies within Sails.js?
Probably doing something wrong...

Thx and kind regards

PS: I will keep looking myself and answer if I find anything.

Comment: I can inform already that switching to yarn does not result in an error. So... this is purely npm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove package-lock.json, commit and push to Heroku !